# how to return to the main menu and divide list into columns?

Tags: c#

I finished my app, however, it failed due to two points below:

1. make a list of weeks divided into 6 columns
2. When "0" is pressed, it needs to go back to the main menu, but, instead, U am getting the phrase, "press any key to exit. how do I fix this?

what have I done wrong?

thank you

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class WorkingSchedule
    {
        public WorkingSchedule()
    {
        Start();
    }

    public void Start()
    {

        int choice = -1;
        while (choice != 0)
        {
            ShowMenu();
            Console.WriteLine("Your Choice :");
            choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Weekends();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Nights();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    return;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option: Choose 0, 1, or 2 Thank you ");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Weekends() // this function is used to 
    {
        for (int x = 1; x <= 52; x += 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Week" + x);
        }
    }
    private void Nights()
    {
        for (int y = 6; y <= 51; y += 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Night" + y);
        }
    }

    private void ShowMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("                    YOUR SCHEDULE PROGRAM                   ");
        Console.WriteLine("Select from the menu which type of schedule you want to see.");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("1 Show a list of the weekends to work .");
        Console.WriteLine("2 Show a list of the nights to work .");
        Console.WriteLine("0 Return to Main Menu               ");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: For the '_make list of weeks divided into 6 columns_', I will recommend using [ask] and [mre]. because you didnt provide enought information on that. Its unclear what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! I appreciate the help. But I didn't understand a 100% I've used "return" but it didn't work. Where should I put it? Could you explain a bit more. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class WorkingSchedule
    {
        public WorkingSchedule()
    {
        Start();
    }

    public void Start()
    {

        int choice = 0;
        while (choice != 3)
        {
            ShowMenu();
            Console.WriteLine("Your Choice :");
            choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Weekends();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Nights();
                    break;
                case 0:
                      {
                         continue;
                      }
                      break;
                case 3 :
                   return; 
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option: Choose 0, 1, or 2 Thank you ");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Weekends() // this function is used to 
    {
        for (int x = 1; x <= 52; x += 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Week" + x);
        }
    }
    private void Nights()
    {
        for (int y = 6; y <= 51; y += 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Night" + y);
        }
    }

    private void ShowMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("                    YOUR SCHEDULE PROGRAM                   ");
        Console.WriteLine("Select from the menu which type of schedule you want to see.");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("1 Show a list of the weekends to work .");
        Console.WriteLine("2 Show a list of the nights to work .");
        Console.WriteLine("0 Return to Main Menu               ");
        Console.WriteLine("3 to exit               ");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: You will show the menu twice. You should just do `continue;` in the `case 0`

Comment: Thank you . I appreciate your help .

Comment: thaks @Charlieface